# iPhone4 how to find out if the power cable is plugged in?

Tags: iphone, ios, power-management

I would like to know if my app is running with an external power cable attached. Is it possible to find out this state at runtime?

An extra question: would this be able to differentiate between true USB power and those external "battery packs"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `UIDevice` property `batteryState`:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryState] == UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging
```

From [UIDevice Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/UIDevice_Class.pdf#page15):

```
typedef enum {
    UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown,
    UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged,
    UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging,
    UIDeviceBatteryStateFull,
} UIDeviceBatteryState;
```

As for your 2nd question.  I don't believe you can determine any difference between a battery pack and a wall charger since the above `UIDeviceBatteryState` flags are the only "states" a device battery can report.  So both a battery pack and wall charger would appear as either `UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging` or `UIDeviceBatteryStateFull` (or `UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged` if the battery pack is plugged in but out of juice).

Answer (score 1):

You can detect whether the battery is charging, but that's as close as you can get with existing APIs – there's no way to detect where the power is "coming from", so to speak.

```
UIDeviceBatteryState batteryState = [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryState;
if (batteryState == UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to include the line,

[[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];

or else batteryState only returns UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown. Perhaps this became necessary since this question was initially asked and answered.  I found the tip here:  [Determine accurate iPhone battery level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490010/about-battery-level-in-iphone).