# iOS - how to detect if power is connected to the iDevice ad is charging

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, power-management

I'm trying to determine if he device is plugged in and charging. How do I find out in ios 5.x or higher?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone4 how to find out if the power cable is plugged in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924368/iphone4-how-to-find-out-if-the-power-cable-is-plugged-in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `UIDevice` to get these info

Use the following

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryState] == UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging)
    NSLog(@"device is conected to power");
```