# USB detection in jailbreak ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, usb, daemon, jailbreak

I'm currently trying to develop daemon on a jailbreak ios device and I'm looking to find a way to detect that the device is to usb.  Is there any plist or anything else that I can monitor to check the usb?  If not, is there a way to compile a GCC app on the ios device with the 4.3 sdk?

Comment: Do you want to do communication over USB to computer?

Comment: No.  I just want to detect usb power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can do that with public APIs.  See [this answer on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7924384/119114).

Note that you probably need to check that the battery state is either **Charging**, or **Full**.  Both would mean that the cable is plugged in.

Also, if you download the `notificationWatcher` utility (part of **Erica Utilities**) from Cydia, and run it on a jailbroken iPhone (connected via Wifi and SSH), you'll see this at the console when you connect/disconnect the USB cable:

> Notification intercepted: com.apple.springboard.fullycharged
>
> Notification intercepted: com.apple.springboard.pluggedin
>
> Notification intercepted: com.apple.springboard.fullycharged

So, I would guess that you can register for notifications in either of the following two ways:

```objc
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled: YES];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self 
                                         selector: @selector(batteryStatus) 
                                             name: UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification 
                                           object: nil];
```

or, use Core Foundation notifications:

```objc
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), //center
                                NULL, // observer
                                plugStatus, // callback
                                CFSTR("com.apple.springboard.pluggedin"), // name
                                NULL, // object
                                CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorHold);
```

and then the callback functions could be:

```objc
- (void) batteryStatus {
    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"batteryStatus" message: @"battery" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}

static void plugStatus(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo) {
    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"plugStatus" message: @"plug" delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    if (userInfo != nil) {
        CFShow(userInfo);
    }
}
```

`com.apple.springboard.pluggedin` is sent when the cable is plugged, **or** unplugged.

Comment: Thank a lot.  I think the log is a good way to go.  That's good idea.  Actually, Is there a way to compile code that would be start by the launch.d without user interaction with xcode.  I have saw the toolchain available but it's quite old now.

Comment: @Bliard, what exactly do you mean **without user interaction with Xcode**?  Do you want to build a **Launch Daemon** process?  Are you talking about starting your code without the user tapping an icon on the home screen (also known as *SpringBoard*)?

Comment: Yes this is it. I want to run a process that would delete some file when I plug the usb cable. Would love to compile something like Erica utility.

Comment: @Bliard, check out [Chris Alvares' blog](http://chrisalvares.com/blog/tag/daemon/) for a good tutorial on creating an iOS launch daemon.  If you put the code I posted above in a daemon, you can achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank.  I saw that already.  Is it possible to install the open chain template in xcode 4.3?

Comment: @Bliard, you're now asking a completely different question (separate from USB connection detection).  You should post a new question (on stack overflow).  Thanks.